# how to retrieve the returned value from the controller in the jsp using the ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp

this is my javascript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function callMe() {
            var districtId = $("#district").val();
            alert(districtId);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addBranch",
                data: "districtId=" + districtId,
                success: function(response) {



                }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

this is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addBranch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody 
List getForm1(@ModelAttribute Branch branch, Model model,@RequestParam("districtId")    
int districtId) {
    try {

       districtVillageList = villageService.getDistrictVillageList(districtId);

    } catch (Exception er) {
        log.error("error in addLoanType=" + er);
    }
    return districtVillageList;
 }
```

I am getting the list in the controller, but as i am new to ajax,i dont know how to retrieve the list in the ajax and use the retrieved values in jsp...Please can any one helo me??

Comment: this may help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209673/using-spring-mvc-and-ajax-to-handle-list-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

As you have returned the list in the controller, just get in the response and iterate it using `for-in` loop 
 something like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function callMe() {
            var districtId = $("#district").val();
            alert(districtId);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addBranch",
                data: "districtId=" + districtId,
                success: function(response) {
                       for (var i in response){
                       // response[i].getterMethodHere
                      }   
                    }
            });
        }    
    </script>
```

try using json objects to send the response instead of list. Learn More from [jquery loop on Json data using $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each) and [jQuery loop over JSON result from AJAX Success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success)